# How can I install Ubuntu on a Portable Haddrive (Enclosure + HardDisk) ?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, usb

this question is not simple as the title suggests. Because I've failed to install Ubuntu on my Portable HD 5 times.

**OK, this is the list of things I have:**

An Elitebook - 1 Internal HD, USB 2.0 Port, Win 7 installed.

A USB Flash Drive - Kingston 8 GB

A Portable HD - A 2.5" SATA HD + A Cheap Enclosure - 650 GB

Another Portable HD - 120 GB

**STATUS:**

My Laptop works fine - no problem. I've installed Kali, Ubuntu, and several other Linux distros on/in my Virtual Machine.

My USB works fine too. I've installed several Linux distros on it - LIVE + Persistent.

My Portable HD is also fine. I can READ | WRITE files. Can create partitions. And it behaves exactly like my Internal HD. When I plug it in my Laptop, it appears in HD section - not in Removable Device section like USB Flash Drive

**What Do I want to Do?**

I am a computer engineering student and I've 3 systems (1 PC + 1 Elitebook + 1 Laptop/Tab). I want to install Ubuntu on my portable HD so that I can just attach that to any of my device and work on my projects. Sorry I can't install Linux on my Laptop or any other device.

**What Did I do so far?**

1. Made my USB Bootable - works fine
2. From Boot menu - I booted to my USB - deleted all partitions
3. Clicked on install Ubuntu
4. Installation started. Something else.
5. My Portable HD appeared there. (sdc). I made an ext4 partition (root /) and a swap partition.
6. Choose sdc (my HD) to install GRUB.
7. Installed Linux.
8. DONE.
9. Reboot. USB Removed.
10. My Portable HD is not appearing in Boot menu.

Just keep trying...

Yeah, it appeared. Selected USB... Windows boots... (GRUB is not loading)

I've tried creating partitions by several methods.

Primary - root + Primary swap
Extended (root + swap)
and few more

**What I expect:**

Ubuntu installs fine. I can see the files. I can see Grub in root. But it does not boot at all.

Why I can boot Ubuntu from USB Flash drive but not from Portable HD?

I've tried booting it from all three systems but no luck. Without Ubuntu - NTFS partitions with no files, my Portable HD appears in Boot menu

But with Ubuntu installed - it does not appear. And if appears it boot directly to Windows.

I've also tried changing boot order, disabling and enabling UEFI, formatting HD, installing another distro.

NO luck at all. Whats wrong with it?

Any help || suggestion || advice ?

Tried: Ubuntu 14.0X, Kali latest, Puppy (4.4.X)

Comment: *Choose sdc (my HD) to install GRUB* so, logically, if you want to boot Ubuntu (and assuming it's a legacy/BIOS installation due to Win7) you need to change the BIOS boot priority.

Comment: "I've also tried changing boot order"

Already tried. No luck.